# Computation of $\int \tanh^5 2x \textrm d x$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Really struggling with a problem here:

I need to find $\int \tanh^5 2x \textrm d x$ - absolutely no idea how to do it.

I tried splitting into $\tanh^2 2x,\tanh^2 2x, \tanh 2x$, and tried using double angle formulas. A complete solution would be really helpful as it also puts me on track for some other problems.

Comment: Where is the integral?

Comment: You may be better off using a paid "tutoring" service.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding the downvotes: the OP has included sufficient context in the last paragraph and the question is not trivial at all.

Comment: @AlexM. I didn't downvote but my guess is those who did may have done so partially because of the (original) title of the question.

Comment: @tilper: I wouldn't rush to downvote just because the word "urgent" was present in the title. The rest of the post was ok.

Comment: I wouldn't either but I see why some people would.  Some may have interpreted the urgency as "I need this for an assignment/exam with a very tight deadline"

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Substitute $2x=t$ than use the fact that:
$$
\int \tanh^n(t)dt=\int \tanh^{n-2}(t)dt- \frac{\tanh^{n-1}(t)}{n-1}
$$

( This is essentially the same as @Archis answer).

Answer (score 2):

I am not much in hyperbolic functions but use reduction formula ( I am writing this on basis of reduction of $\tan^n(x)$ so $\int\tanh^5(x)dx=\int\tanh^2(x)\tanh^3(x)dx=\int\tanh^3(x)\ sech^2(x)dx-\int\tanh^3(x)dx$ now in first integral put $tanh=u$ so $\ sech^2(x)dx=du$ repeat same reduction for $\tanh^3(x)$ hope you get it now

Answer (score 0):

First write the integral as $\int \tanh 2x \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \int \tanh y \, dy$. Write $\tanh y = \frac{\sinh y}{\cosh y}$ so looking at $\int \frac{\sinh^5 y}{\cosh^5 y} \, dy$, next put $\sinh^5 y= \sinh^4 y \times \sinh y$, then two further steps: $\sinh y \, dy$ can be related to $d \cosh y$ and then think of replacing $\sinh^4 y$ in terms of powers of $\cosh y$.

Comment: Putting "\" before some standard function names makes them upright with correct spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Do a u-substitution.

$$\frac{1}{2}\int \tanh^5 \space u \space du \space = -\frac{\tanh^4 u}{8} - \frac{\tanh^2 u}{4} + \frac{\log(\cosh(u))}{2} + c$$

From the identity $$\int \tanh^p \space x \space dx = -\frac{\tanh^{p-1}x}{p-1} + \int \tanh^{p-2}x \space dx$$

An alternative method:

$$\frac{1}{2}\int \tanh^{5}u \space du = -\frac{1}{2}\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\tanh^{6-2k} \space u}{5-2k} + u\bigg) $$

These come from *Table of Integrals, Series, and Products, Seventh Edition*, Chapter 2, section 2.424, examples 1 & 2.